# how to map the array data using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
let userData = {
  myData: [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Russell',
      country: 'Windes'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Smith',
      country: 'USA'
    }
  ],
  ownerData: [{
      id: 3,
      name: 'Watson',
      country: 'Australia'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'Marcus',
      country: 'England'
    }
  ]
};

let records = arrayMapped(userData)
  .then(res => console.log(res));


async function arrayMapped(user) {
  let best4 = [];

  user.myData.forEach(async(res, i) => {

    res.myTeam = [];

    user.ownerData.forEach(async(myTeam, j) => {
      res.myTeam = myTeam;
    });

    best4.push(res);

  });

  return best4;
}
```

array pushing behaving weired

I was expecting myTeam id 3 should be under 1 id and myTeam 4 id would be under id 2.

but currently it is taking 4 id to all what is the reason please guide

Thanks

Comment: You're overwriting the same `res.myTeam` each time through the inner `for` loop. So every `res` will get the last `ownerData`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to iterate over the two arrays in parallel, so you shouldn't use nested loops. Just use the index of the `myData` loop as the index into the `ownerData` array.

```js
let userData = {
  myData: [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Russell',
      country: 'Windes'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Smith',
      country: 'USA'
    }
  ],
  ownerData: [{
      id: 3,
      name: 'Watson',
      country: 'Australia'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'Marcus',
      country: 'England'
    }
  ]
};

let records = arrayMapped(userData)
  .then(res => console.log(res));

async function arrayMapped(user) {
  let best4 = [];

  user.myData.forEach(async(res, i) => {
    res.myTeam = user.ownerData[i];
    best4.push(res);
  });

  return best4;
}
```

I notice that you have the functions declared `async`, but they don't do anything asynchronously. If the real functions do, see [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)